# In excel, how do I group duplicates according to whether or not they meet a certain condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of people with each row showing a person, and their usage of a platform in percentages. if a person uses more than 1 platform, they will appear in multiple rows, each for a different platform (and each row shows their percentage usage of that platform).
rows that show a person uses a platform more than 60% have another column called "significant use" and its content is 1. rows that show a person using a platform less than 60% have that column's content as 0.

so a person uses platform A 61%, and platform B 39% will have "1" in significant in Platform A's row and "0" in platform B's row.

Another person uses 3 platforms, each 33%. for that person, all 3 rows will show "0" in the "Significant" column.

I want a way to differentiate between people who have more than 60% in any platform and people who don't have any platform they use more than 60%.

I've tried to subtotal, hoping to sum up the 0s and 1s in significance (so if one of the rows is more than 60%, the total will be 1, and if no row is more than 60% the total will be 0), but either I get messed up results or Excel just gets stuck.

there are 74k rows, which shouldn't be that problematic.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some sample data. Otherwise it is very difficult to figure out exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Do your percentages reflect how each person divides his time or how each person accounts for the usage a platform receives?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the if function. 
Here's how I did a test:
First: 3 columns 2 rows. Fisrt row names: A1=Mike, B1=Bob, C1=Betty
2nd row enter usage values: A2=20, B2=40, C2=70

Elsewhere on the same worksheet make set of 3 col 2 rows
First row names: Mike, Bob, Betty 
Second row if functions:
if function:
Double click Fx next to cell value (the one stating above/below 60% usage)
IF=  A2 < 60 
True= "Usage below 60%"
False= "Usage above 60%"
I looked it up and found the info in 60 sec. Using the help inside the if pop-up window
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Steve, but that doesn't really help me. or rather, that part I already got. But my problem is that I have 3 rows for Mike, 5 rows for Bob and 2 rows for Betty (for instance). Mike's rows add up to 100% and so do all the other people's, but Mike's first row is 75, the other 2 are 10 and 15. Bob's 5 rows are 20 each. So I want to show the difference between Mike and Bob, which is that Mike uses a platform more than 60%, whereas Bob doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
=1*(0<sumproduct((A1:A5="Mike")*(B1:B5>=0.6)))
```

Change the ranges to suit your data.
This function turns (Mike, Mike, Bob, Charlie) into (1,1,0,0) and (0.4,0.7,0.8,0.2) into (0,1,1,0) and performs a sumproduct on the results.
Note that this is a volatile formula and may slow your sheet over 74k rows. Set calculation to manual if so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about how the names and percentages are organized on your spreadsheet.  Anyway you could post an image just so we can have a better idea?

by your description, I think it looks like this:

[image]

Is this about right?